# Responding appropriately with a 415 error in a RESTful web app

Tags: rest, http

I am building a web application which can accept resource representations via `PUT`, `POST` and `PATCH` in both `x-www-form-urlencoded` and JSON formats. If I receive a request body in another format, I would like to send a `415` response, plus some additional data declaring what formats I do accept (in a similar manner to the `405` response's mandatory `Allow:` header). I have seen on one answer at [HTTP 406 and 415 error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294483/http-406-and-415-error-codes) where the person answering did not know if there was such a mechanism defined, RFC 2616 mentions nothing in this regard, and some cursory Googling turns up nothing either.

I would like to just use `Accept:` even though that is defined as a request header. It seems most appropriate just to re-use it for this response. Do folks agree? Does anyone have a better suggestion?

**Edit:** I have since found [Specify supported media types when sending "415 unsupported media type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343165/specify-supported-media-types-when-sending-415-unsupported-media-type) which asks specifically if there is a standard for this. The correct and accepted answer was basically **no**, but the respondant there also had the same idea as me, that Accept would be a good header to use to provide this information. This prompted [a message](http://osdir.com/ml/ietf-http-wg/2011-12/msg00187.html) from [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) to the HTTP Working Group asking if it should be defined what sending an `Accept:` header in a response should mean. That email only received one response, which agreed that it was needed and that Accept seemed appropriate.

Note that I am not asking if I am *permitted* to send an Accept header, any header is allowed to be sent in either direction, but only those defined in the spec have *meaning* (semantics) to intermediaries, and also, any unexpected headers not prefixed with `X-` might clash with future versions of HTTP. This doesn't bother me.

Comment: all of my open questions are still awaiting acceptable answers. I am keen to see new answers posted to them.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask questions that can be answered in an acceptable way.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) is a request-header. It is **wrong** to use it in a response.

To [quote Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation),

> Content negotiation is a mechanism defined in the HTTP specification that makes it possible to serve different versions of a document (or more generally, a resource representation) at the same URI, so that user agents can specify which version fit their capabilities the best.

So it is the *client* who says in the request what media types he can `Accept`. If the server is not able to deliver this media type he responds with `406 Not Acceptable`.

Since the client must be able to deal with the returned representation of the requested resource, it should specify which media types it can understand. It can specifiy *multiple* media types:

```
Accept: application/json, application/xml, x-www-form-urlencoded
```

If the client really wants to accept *any* media type, it can set

```
Accept: */*
```

The server will set a proper `Content-Type` response header even for such a request.

Comment: _"So it is the client who says in the request what media types he can Accept. If the server is not able to deliver this media type he responds with 415 Unsupported Media Type."_ - but the question is how a _server_ can respond that it doesn't understand the given `Content-Type`.

Comment: The server does by setting the status to 415. What you want is the server to tell what it *can* understand. There is no way for this in HTTP.

Comment: @Tichodroma No, @CodeCaster is correcting a mistake in your answer. You said _"If the server is not able to deliver this media type he responds with `415 Unsupported Media Type`."_ The server should instead send `406 Not Acceptable` if it cannot fulfil the conditions of an Accept request header. A 415 response is correct in the situation I describe.

Comment: @Nicholas Right, edited. Still the main point of my answer is that `Accept` is *not* to be set by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You receiving an unrecognized Content-Type will most probably be from a developer currently implementing a client to your service. Since there does not exist a mechanism for a server to advertise its supported content types, you might as well mention in the message body what types you do support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard mechanism to do this but you may be able to slightly re-purpose the Alternates header http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2295.txt to do what you want.

Comment: I do not understand how that could work. Alternates provides URIs of other representations. I am looking for a way to tell the client what format it's request body should be in. Please expand upon your answer if to explain your idea further.