# How to indicate supported media types after a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, http, content-type, http-status-code-415

For example an endpoint gets a POST request with content type `application/vtortola+json;version=2`, however such endpoint just supports `version=1`, so an HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type is returned.

I wonder if there is any specific HTTP mechanism to indicate the media types that are actually supported by such endpoint in the response. This is a notification endpoint, so caller does not do a GET of any kind prior. The `Accept` header is just for requests, not for responses.

An option would be the client issuing HEAD to check the supported media types if an HTTP 415 happens. However this implies that I have to create a HEAD endpoint per each POST endpoint.

Comment: For WebApi, you can implement a custom media type formatter and add the media type to the SupportedMediaTypes collection.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wilde-accept-post-03 might be of interest.

Comment: Interesting. But that means the client must issue an HTTP OPTION to find out, since that header is just for that type of call, not as part of a POST response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify supported media types when sending "415 unsupported media type"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343165/specify-supported-media-types-when-sending-415-unsupported-media-type)